# jQuery character counter issue

Tags: jquery, count, character

Found this very simple code to show character counts for my text inputs:

http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/jquery_word_character_counter

I modified it like below. However it isn't working correctly when backspacing. it doesn't display the char count correctly. Can somebody help fix this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.word_count').each(function() {
        $(this).parent().find('.counter').html('Only ' + $(this).attr("size") + ' characters allowed');
        // bind on key up event  
        $(this).keydown(function(event) {            
            k = event.keyCode;
            // eat backspaces, tabs, and CRs
            if(($(this).attr("size") - $(this).val().length) == 0&&(k!=8&&k!=9&&k!=13)) {
                event.preventDefault();
            } else {
              if($(this).val().length==0) {
                $(this).parent().find('.counter').html('Only ' + $(this).attr("size") + ' characters allowed');
              } else {
                $(this).parent().find('.counter').html(($(this).attr("size") - $(this).val().length-1) + ' characters left');
              }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mrbaseball34/RymcJ/16/

Comment: Why don't you count the val().length every blur keyup() event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a lot of things that could be improved about that script. The source of your problem is described by the comment:

```
// eat backspaces, tabs, and CRs
```

Next, it uses the `keydown` event, so it might have certain other problems. It also takes the count from the `size` attribute rather than the more correct `maxlength` attribute. Here's how I would rewrite it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.word_count').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var counter = $this.parent().find('.counter');
        var maxlength = $this.attr('maxlength');

        counter.text('Only ' + maxlength + ' characters allowed');

        $this.bind('input keyup keydown', function() {
            var value = $this.val();

            if(value.length > 0) {
                counter.text((maxlength - $this.val().length) + ' characters left');
            } else {
                counter.text('Only ' + maxlength + ' characters allowed');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/muBnL/)

Comment: Very nice. Also handles clipboard functions.

Comment: great answer and example code was superb thanks - adding 'input' along with keyup and keydown fixed my issue

Answer (score 2):

That's what you call "over-programmed". See: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/esXHS/1/).

It works just as well if not better (in that it actually recognizes backspaces).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.word_count').keyup(function() {
        var $input = $(this);
        $('.counter', $input.parent()).text($input.val().length);
    });
});
```

For something this simple, all you care about is `keyups` in the field. Sure, this catches things like <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>, etc. but since all you're doing is just counting the length of the field and updating a span, it hardly matters. Perfect case of KISS.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var input   = $('input.word_count');
    var counter = $('.counter');
    var size    = input.attr('size');

    counter.text(size);

    input.keyup(function() {
        new_size = size - input.val().length;

        if (!(new_size >= 0)) {
            input.val(input.val().slice(0, -1));
        } else {
            counter.text(new_size);
        }
    })
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/powtac/XHsz6/18/ for a working demo.